# Sorting a HTML table with PHP after input from database

Tags: php, html, mysql, sorting, html-table

I'm creating a HTML table with data-rows from a MySQL database and some calculated values, like this:

```
    <?php

$connection = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die('Connection failed!');
mysql_select_db('MyDB', $connection);
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM DB_TABLE');

?>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Heading 1</th>
    <th scope="col">Tariefplan</th>
    <th scope="col">Abonnementskost</th>
    <th scope="col">Maandelijkse korting</th>
    <th scope="col">Contractduur</th>
    <th scope="col">Inbegrepen in bundel</th>
    <th scope="col">Tarieven buiten bundel</th>
    <th scope="col"></th>

    <th scope="col">Bereken minuten</th>
    <th scope="col">Bereken SMS'en</th>
    <th scope="col">Bereken MB's</th>
    <th scope="col"></th>

    <th scope="col">Totale prijs normaal</th>
    <th scope="col">Totale prijs promotie</th>
    <th scope="col">Totale prijs contract</th>
  </tr>

<?php
while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
?>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row"><?php echo $data['provider']; ?></th>
        <td><?php echo $data['planname']; ?></td>
        <td>&euro; <?php echo $data['price_normal']; ?> per maand<br />
            <sub>gedurende <?php echo ($data['contract_duration']-$data['promo_duration']); ?> maanden</sub></td>
        <td>- &euro; <?php echo $data['promo_discount']; ?> per maand<br />
            <sub>gedurende <?php echo $data['promo_duration']; ?> maanden</sub><br />
            <sub>promotie geldig tot <?php echo $data['promo_valid']; ?></sub></td>
        <td><?php echo $data['contract_duration']; ?> maanden</td>
        <td>
            <ul>
                <li><?php echo $data['included_min']; ?> minuten</li>
                <li><?php echo $data['included_sms']; ?> SMS'en</li>
                <li><?php echo $data['included_mb']; ?> MB's</li>
                <li>&euro; <?php echo $data['included_value']; ?> belwaarde</li>
            </ul>
        </td>
        <td>
            <ul>
                <li>&euro; <?php echo $data['price_min']; ?> per minuut</li>
                <li>&euro; <?php echo $data['price_sms']; ?> per SMS</li>
                <li>&euro; <?php echo $data['price_mb']; ?> per MB</li>
            </ul>
        </td>
        <td></td>


        <td>
            <?php
                if ($_POST['used_min'] <= $data['included_min']) {
                    $calc_min = 0;
                }
                else {
                    $calc_min = ($_POST['used_min'] - $data['included_min']) * $data['price_min'];
                }
                echo '&euro; ' . $calc_min;
            ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php
                if ($_POST['used_sms'] <= $data['included_sms']) {
                    $calc_sms = 0;
                }
                else {
                    $calc_sms = ($_POST['used_sms'] - $data['included_sms']) * $data['price_sms'];
                }
                echo '&euro; ' . $calc_sms;
            ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php
                if ($_POST['used_mb'] <= $data['included_mb']) {
                    $calc_mb = 0;
                }
                else {
                    $calc_mb = ($_POST['used_mb'] - $data['included_mb']) * $data['price_mb'];
                }
                echo '&euro; ' . $calc_mb;
            ?>
        </td>
        <td></td>


        <td>
            <?php
                $used_total = ($calc_min + $calc_sms + $calc_mb);
                if ($data['included_value'] > $used_total) {
                    $total_price_normal = $data['price_normal'];
                }
                else {
                    $total_price_normal = ($data['price_normal'] + $used_total);
                }
                echo '&euro; ' . $total_price_normal . ' per maand';
            ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php
                $total_price_discount = ($total_price_normal - $data['promo_discount']);
                echo '&euro; ' . $total_price_discount . ' per maand';
            ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php
                $total_price_contract = ($total_price_normal * ($data['contract_duration']-$data['promo_duration'])) + ($total_price_discount * $data['promo_duration']);
                echo '&euro; ' . $total_price_contract . ' per maand ' . $data['contract_duration'] . ' na maanden';
            ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

The last column in the table is a variable value witch calculates a total amount. This is NOT listed in the database. 
I want to output this table to an browserpage and let is be sort on that last column.

With PHP `sort()` or `asort()` function that doesn't work fine.

Does someone have a solution?

Answer (score 3):

Do the calculation in the SQL query, and let the database handle the sorting

Comment: How do I do that. (Sorry, I'm new to PHP)

Comment: It's not much to do with PHP, all to do with MySQL

Answer (score 2):

You have calculate the values first and then create the table. Or use some javascript. So you have to go trough $result and put calculated values in array and after that you may sort and print to table with values, sorted by that last value.

Comment: This seems to be interested and the most easy. But how do I put calculated values in array?

Comment: first you get your results to $result, then use foreach to iterate result array (e.q. foreach $result as $key => $row). in foreach you do like this: $result[$key]['table']['someColumn'] = calculatedValue; and after that you can use php functions to sort the array.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be better if you first iterate through your results, do your calculations and put everything into an array. Then you can sort the array like you want with any PHP function and output it. The best thing with this approach is, you will have a cleaner output of the table because do all calculations and stuff away from the HTML output ;)

The other idea is, that you do it like you do above and then use a tablesorter in i.e. Javascript/jQuery to sort your rows afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible but it might be tricky to do this using PHP. For a quick fix you could try this jquery solution which does what you want and get you up and running very quickly.

http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Demo

Answer (score 1):

> With PHP sort() or asort() function that doesn't work fine.

if you meant it sort like this `1, 10, 12, 2` you can use [natsort();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php).